# CakePHP Getting Language Strings from Labels with Extract

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I am getting language strings from labels with extract.

I have the following code in a view:

```
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('observee', array('label' => __(Observee), 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $resultStaff, 'class' => 'input-large select')); ?>
```

When I run  cake i18n extract I get the other language strings from the view as expected but not any of the ones that are being used in labels.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Comment: ahh my bad. didn't have single quotes around the string

Answer (score 1):

Careful

```
__(Observee)
```

is not valid PHP, your IDE should also warn you about it

Correct would be:

```
__('Observee')
```

Comment: So if my answer is the answer to your obviously quite trivial issue you are welcome to hit the "correct answer" button :P